# Is it possible to set ServletContext timeout?

Tags: java

I am using context to share login sessions. I use `setAttibute` function. 
I know `HttpSession` has the property of setting the maximum timeout time.

Is it possible to set context attribute a similar way?

```
ServletContext context = httpservlet.getServletContext();


context.setAttribute("currentSessionUser", username);
```

Thanks

Comment: there is one instance of `ServeltContext` per web application. Why u using this for storing user information?

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that. the context is application-wide, and you will get very unexpected results when more than one user is browsing your site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the attribute **currentSessionUser** in **HttpSession** and it is relevant ,rather than ServletContext, ServletContext will get destroyed ,when any reload happens(JAR Deployment).

```
request.getSession(false).setAttribute("currentSessionUser", username);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define session-timeout attribute for your application. Write in your web.xml:

```
<session-config>
   <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do like this:

1. put an object in both ServletContext and HttpSession:

   ```
   String username = getUsername();
   TheObject theObject = null;
   if(session.getServletContext().getAttribute(THE_SESSION_KEY + "_" + theObject.getCurrentUsername()) == null) {
        theObject = new TheObject(username);
        session.setAttribute(THE_SESSION_KEY, theObject);
        session.getServletContext().setAttribute(THE_SESSION_KEY + "_" + username, theObject);
   }
   else {
        theObject = (TheObject)session.getServletContext().getAttribute(THE_SESSION_KEY + "_" + theObject.getCurrentUsername());
   }
   ```
2. Create a session event listener

   ```
   public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
       if(arg0.getSession().getAttribute(THE_SESSION_KEY) != null) {
           TheObject theObject = (TheObject)arg0.getSession().getAttribute(THE_SESSION_KEY);
           arg0.getSession().getServletContext().removeAttribute(THE_SESSION_KEY + "_" + theObject.getCurrentUsername());
       }
   }
   ```